# CS0117: 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor' does not contain a definition for 'Text'

Tags: asp.net, literals

I received this error when trying to put a couple of C# projects live. The sites were working locally in VS 2010 but on live they threw the following error:

CS0117: 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor' does not contain a definition for 'Text'

This was the code having the issue in the code file of the master page:

```
litHome.Text = "active";
```

In the source the master page I had this:

```
<li><a href="Default.aspx" class="<asp:Literal ID="litHome" runat="server" />">home</a></li>
```

The error being thrown appeared to think I was setting the text property of an HTML Anchor.

I've just fixed this myself but after not being able to find the solution on here (or Google) I thought I'd post it for anyone else having the problem. Please see my comments below as I'm not allowed to answer this yet.

Comment: Eh, what have you posted? You've just shown an error message!

Comment: HtmlAnchor doesn't have a `Text` property. It's a too localized problem, you shoud drop the question itself. It's my opinion.

Comment: Did you convert the control from any other type (having `Text` property) to `HtmlAnchor`, which could cause this?

Comment: Left that as a comment as not allowed to post the answer for a few hours yet.
Dave Rook: Yes, I was trying to post the answer afterwards
Matías Fidemraizer: Yes I know, this was in a literal.
shahkalpesh: No, this appears to be something new I've just experience in VS 2010, not sure why I'm only seeing it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was down to having a literal inside an anchor tag (used to dynamically set a CSS class) with quotes instead of apostrophes. Done this many times but only today when putting 2 new sites live did this problem come up (perhaps someone can explain why it's only coming up now, new validation in VS service pack perhaps?) Anyway, the following code errors:
`<li><a href="Default.aspx" class="<asp:Literal ID="litHome" runat="server" />">home</a></li>` Needs to be:
`<li><a href="Default.aspx" class="<asp:Literal ID='litHome' runat='server' />">home</a></li>` Hope that helps someone

Answer (score 0):

sir

html controls doesn't have (.Text) extensions in this case you can use (.Value) instead to solve your problem ,it will return u same thing which in returned in case of .Text.If u still face ant problem just let me know which control u r using

in code behind

string abc=htmlTextbox.Value;

Comment: Hi Rohit, not the issue, it was an ASP.NET literal control. Needed to be <li><a href="Default.aspx" class="<asp:Literal ID='litHome' runat='server' />">home</a></li> and not <li><a href="Default.aspx" class="<asp:Literal ID="litHome" runat="server" />">home</a></li>